# Getting the error no such interface supported when trying to create an applicaton from IIS

Tags: iis

I am trying to create an application from IISManager, ( Right click -> Properties -> Create Application). but I am gitting the error "IIS Error no such interface supported" Every thing in IIS is installed. And I am using Windows server 2003 64 bits, I am event getting the error when right click the website and clicking properties, Any body knows what might be the issue?

I tried unregistering and rgistering the  iisrstap.dll dll using the command C:\WINNT\system32> regsvr32 iisrstap.dll but kept getting same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by removing the IIS complete and then reinstalling it again.